# How to implement click through window except on element in electron?

Tags: reactjs, electron, click-through

I am trying to implement

> click through the window except on element

in `electron` with `react` as frontend, for this I found interesting package `electron-transparency-mouse-fix` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-transparency-mouse-fix/v/1.0.0-beta), the demo in the repo is based on typescript,
therefore I am bit confused with how to integrate it on my existing `electron-react` project.

A guidance on this is highly appreciated!

Here is my entry point of electron `main.js` file.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;
const path = require('path');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
const ipc  = electron.ipcRenderer;



let mainWindow = null;
app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
});
app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
});
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 2024,
    height: 1024,
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    hasShadow: false,
    title: "Lauda Lasan Window"
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`);
  // mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true);
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })


  /* Set did-fail-load listener once */
  mainWindow.webContents.on("did-fail-load", function() {
    console.log("did-fail-load");

    // mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');

  });

  mainWindow.on('page-title-updated', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows and macOS, an optional parameter can be used to forward mouse move messages to the web page, allowing events such as mouseleave to be emitted:

**main.js**

```
const { BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('node:path')

const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        width: 2024,
        height: 1024,
        transparent: true,
        frame: false,
        resizable: false,
        hasShadow: false,
        title: "Lauda Lasan Window",
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
  }
})

ipcMain.on('set-ignore-mouse-events', (event, ignore, options) => {
  const win = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender)
  win.setIgnoreMouseEvents(ignore, options)
})
```

**preload.js**

```
let isMouseOverInteractiveElement = false;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const interactiveElements = 
document.querySelectorAll('.interactive');

interactiveElements.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        isMouseOverInteractiveElement = true;
        ipcRenderer.send('set-ignore-mouse-events', false);
    });

    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        isMouseOverInteractiveElement = false;
        ipcRenderer.send('set-ignore-mouse-events', true, { forward: true });
    });
});
```

});

and now all you have to is make any elements that want to accept mouse events have a class of interactive and only those classes will not be clickthrough but the rest of the window will be.

Happy Days :)